# How to search for a number with a parameter?

Tags: android, sqlite

I have two tables, created by the following statements:

```
    create table maintable (_id integer primary key, name)
    create table foreigntable (_id integer primary key, object, foreign key (object) references maintable(_id)
```

I'd like to query `foreigntable` for all items referencing a specific object in `maintable`. Let's say the `id` of interest in `maintable` is stored in `objectId`.

**Why does the following code return no results?**

```
 Cursor dataCursor = database.query("foreigntable", null, "object=?", new String[] { Long.toString(objectId)}, null, null, null);
```

I get results with the following query:

```
 Cursor dataCursor = database.rawQuery("select * from foreigntable where object=" + objectId, null);
```

What also works:

```
Cursor dataCursor = database.query("foreigntable", null, "object="+objectId, null, null, null, null);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```java
"object=?", new String[] { Long.toString(objectId)}
```

This code compares the values in the `object` column against a string.
This comparison will always fail because numbers are not strings.

While using parameters is a good idea in general, Android's database API allows nothing but strings, and when you have a number, you should insert it directly into the SQL query string.

Comment: Bummer, thanks! Personally I don't agree with that design, but there's certainly an explanation for it.